# Cron Bash: can't run bash file with cron

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron, pipenv

I have a Python script which I run from a pipenv environment.

I want to run that every minute using cron, but I have not been successful and the solutions I could find have not worked for me.

First I tried:

```
* * * * * cd /home/santiago/flaskpostgres/writeText && pipenv run python3 main.py
```

But I got nothing.

I tried searching for a solution and a bash file was recommended on several places, so I changed the line to be

```
* * * * * bash /home/santiago/hello.sh
```

and wrote a bash file named hello.sh that contains

```bash
#! usr/bin/bash
cd /home/santiago/flaskpostgres/writeText
pipenv run python3 main.py
```

I also changed permissions on hello.sh with

```
chmod +x hello.sh
```

but also nothing.

The bash file by itself works, I have tested that in isolation, but cron does not seem to run it.

cron does work, when I tested with this line

```
* * * * * echo "hello" >> /tmp/test.txt
```

That worked without a problem, its just this python file i cant get to work

In case its helpful the contents of the python file located at flaskpostgres/writeText/main.py are:

```py
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample.txt', 'a') as file_object:
    # Append 'hello' at the end of file
    file_object.write(f"{datetime.now()} \n")
    # Close the file
    file_object.close()
```

this is sort of a Dummy python file, the real one I want to schedule its a bit more complex and has several side effects, so I can't run it every time I want to test cron.

The server is running Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: The usual way to run a python program is `python main.py`.  Why are you using pipenv?

Comment: rigth now im just testing to get the script working.

the real python file i want to schedule does need pipenv but i cant be running it everytime i want to test cron as it has several side efects

Comment: FWIW stderr goes to your mail by default. try running `mail` and see if you get any errors that are helpful. My guess is that `pipenv` is not within your cron `$PATH`, which is different from what your interactive shell gets.

Comment: What daniel said: for all it's worth, ~70% of problems w/ cron are `$PATH` related, a good number pertains to trying to run something that needs a GUI (which the cron environment doesn't know about).  And most can be debugged by looking at mail (or if that's suppressed by redirecting stderr & stdout to a file from cron).

Comment: im not getting any error on either stderr (console) or my mail, i tried adding
MAILTO="mail@domain-name.com"
but that did not work either.

is there somethign obvious im not getting?

Comment: Also your shebang  #! usr/bin/bash should be #!/usr/bin/bash instead

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned it was indeed a PATH thing.

I updated the path of my bash file to be the same as the one its used when interacting with the shell and it worked